# How can I get MediaWiki to ignore page views from a Google Search Appliance?

Tags: mediawiki, web-crawler, google-search-appliance

The page view counter on each [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org) page seems like a great way to identify popular pages which are worth putting more effort into keeping up-to-date and useful, but I've hit a problem.

We use a [Google Search Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html) to index our MediaWiki installation. The problem I have is that the GSA increments the page view counter each time it crawls the page. This completely dominates the statistics, swamping the views made by real users.

I know how to [reset the page counters](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki_FAQ#How_do_I_reset_the_popular_page_counters) to start again. But is there a way to configure MediaWiki to ignore page requests from the GSA for the purposes of counting page views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done by adding a condition in Article.php:

*includes/Article.php:2861:function viewUpdates():*

```
if( !$wgDisableCounters && !$wgUser->isAllowed('bot') && $this->getID() ) {
```

add:

```
&& strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'gsa-crawler') === false
```

where gsa-crawler is part of the default gsa UA...

another way is to setup Forms Authentication in GSA, and have it login to wikimedia as a user in the bot group..

Comment: Works perfectly! Note that you don't have to hack the code directly - I added this extra condition to LocalSettings.php, so it's maintainable across version upgrades.

Answer (score 3):

We added this snippet to LocalSettings.php, with great success:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'gsa-crawler') !== FALSE) {
  $wgDisableCounters = TRUE;
}
```

Thanks!