# How can I get MediaWiki to ignore page views from Recommind?

Tags: php, web-crawler, mediawiki

Is it possible to get MediaWiki to ignore the page views of the enterprise search tool [Recommind](http://www.recommind.com/products/axcelerate-ediscovery)?  We want to prevent Recommind from completely overshadowing our human page views.

I have seen it is possible to do so for [Google Search Appliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096170/how-can-i-get-mediawiki-to-ignore-page-views-from-a-google-search-appliance).

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: How does Recommind crawl the page? Does it use its own user-agent-string?

Answer (score 2):

The user-agent-string is configurable in the Recommind crawler and is arbitrary.  You can adjust the code from the Google Search Appliance example to ignore the configured user-agent-string.